# Sails fails to lift

Tags: node.js, sails.js

On giving the sails lift command I get the following error. The command was working a few moments ago and has stopped working all of a sudden

```
error: A hook (`controllers`) failed to load!
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected string
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at C:\Users\All Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\include-all\index.js:129:29
at Array.forEach (native)
at requireAll (C:\Users\All Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\include-all\index.js:44:9)
at buildDictionary (C:\Users\All Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-build-dictionary\index.js:68:14)
at Function.module.exports.optional (C:\Users\All Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-build-dictionary\index.js:160:9)
at Hook.loadControllers (C:\Users\All Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\moduleloader\index.js:313:23)
at Hook.wrapper [as loadControllers] (C:\Users\All Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\lodash\index.js:3095:19)
at Hook.loadAndRegisterControllers (C:\Users\All Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\controllers\to-load-and-register-controllers.js:33:19)
at Hook.initialize (C:\Users\All Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\controllers\index.js:59:12)
```

Comment: There is likely a syntax error in one of your controllers

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix  your syntax error in registerControllers.js line 33

Comment: There is no `registerControllers.js`. If you meant `to-load-and-register-controllers.js`, then its a file in an installed dependency (`sailsjs`) and is not the problem. That file loads all controllers, and if it errors out like that, it means there is likely an error in one the controllers

Comment: use comments more often

Answer (score 0):

Without your code it's difficult to say. There is likely an error at your controller call. Check your quotes, maybe you put two quotes like this :

```
ng-controller=""mycontroller" <!-- error -->
```

or

```
ng-controller='my_controller" <!-- error -->
```

or simply a random character you may have written inadvertently on a random location of your file. In that case, and at the condition you developed your project using a version control system (git, svn) you can display your recent modification since your last commit by doing the command `git(or svn) diff` at the root of your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can see error details with running your project

```
sails lift --silly
```